# Saving an POJO to DB using spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

As far as I know, the `save()` method from a Spring Data JPA repository fetches the relevant record from the table, checks if such a records exists in the db, and if it exists then the record is updated else a new record is inserted.

My question is, if I retrieve a record using the `findById()` method, perform certain operations on the retrieved record, and then call the `save()` method, will Spring Data JPA fetch the record again, or as it is already attached to the entity manager, will it just update it.

Comment: The save doesn't do such a thing and thus your understanding is wrong. It will check if an id is set, if so it will call `merge` if not it will call `persist` it will not retrieve anything. If you do a `findById` and do changes you don't need to call `save` as it is already managed and attached to an `EntityManager` the changes are persisted automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I turn on the show-sql property, the logs show a select statement and an insert statement when the save method is called. How does that work?

Comment: That is the `merge` behavior of JPA but that has nothing to do withSpring Data JPA as that would happen without it as well. So Spring Data JPA fetches nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If in your database duplicate data exists in your database, a unique constraints exception will be thrown when persisting the data.